# Removing newlines in middle of function call in source code

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk, grep

I have a source code (in C) which is formatted and newlines are added in the middle of function calls. 
for example I have

```
CALL_A( par1, par2, 12345);
```

and somewhere else I have

```
CALL_A(par1, par2
      ,12345);
```

I need to find the numbers being passed as 3rd parameter of function. 
I have used this sed command to remove the newlines but it doesn't match it:

```
cat source.c | sed -e ':a; /CALL_A*$/ { N; s/$//; ba; }'
```

Any suggestions on how to get rid of the newline in the middle of function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sed -e ':a; /CALL_A[^)]*$/{N; s/\n *//; ba}'
```

Your current version will not work for the following reasons:

- `/CALL_A*$/` won't match the calls, the `*` in regex repeats the previous element, so you are looking for lines that end with `CALL_` and then any number of `A`.  I changed this to `/CALL_A[^)]*$/` so that it will match lines that have `CALL_A` followed by any number of characters that are not `)`, that way you will not match any lines that have the call on a single line.
- `s/$//` won't do anything, `$` matches at the end of the line but it does not match the newline character, so replacing it won't do any good.  Instead I used `s/\n *//`, which will remove the newline character and any leading spaces from the next line.

Comment: Thanks! works great. Only thing is that close parenthesis can be replaced by a semicolon so nested parenthesis as parameters are accepted: sed -e ':a; /CALL_A[^;]*$/{N; s/\n *//; ba}'